# How do I use perl like sed?

Tags: perl

I have a file that has some entries like

```
--ERROR--- Failed to execute the command with employee Name="shayam" Age="34"

--Successfully executed the command with employee Name="ram" Age="55"

--ERROR--- Failed to execute the command with employee Name="sam" Age="23"

--ERROR--- Failed to execute the command with employee Name="yam" Age="3"
```

I have to extract only the Name and Age of those for whom the command execution was failed.
in this case i need to extract shayam 34 sam 23 yam 3. I need to do this in perl. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your title makes it not clear. Anyway...

```
while(<>) {
 next if !/^--ERROR/;
 /Name="([^"]+)"\s+Age="([^"]+)"/;
 print $1, "  ", $2, "\n";
}
```

can do it reading from stdin; of course, you can change the reading loop to anything else and the print with something to populate an hash or whatever according to your needs.

Comment: In what sense is this using perl like sed?  This is using perl like _perl_.  I prefer the invocation in a different answer below.

Comment: You prefer, and I should care… The OP disagreed with you and this closes the issue and flags your comment as irrelevant. Moreover maybe you, as others before you, failed to grasp the broader, weaker, looser, not literal sense of the expression “like sed” used by the OP in the title. Not my fault. Every answer can always be made better, sure, but the OP was ok with it quickly, hence to me it's over. Other needs can be satisfied by any better (in your humble opinion) answers. (Btw I often used sed `-f` since complicated editing can be hard to be done as oneliner—was I using sed like perl??)

Answer (score 38):

```
perl -p -e 's/../../g' file
```

Or to inline replace:

```
perl -pi -e 's/../../g' file
```

Comment: apparently on windows 7 you need to put " instead of '.

Answer (score 28):

As a one-liner:

```
perl -lne '/^--ERROR---.*Name="(.*?)" Age="(.*?)"/ && print "$1 $2"' file
```

Comment: What eerily similar answers!  I never remember `-l` though, ++.

Comment: I'm trying to use this technique, and I get one line of output for each match, but it only prints blank lines. If remove the "$1 $2" then it prints the whole matched line. Any idea why I can't seem to print the captures?

Comment: @SteveJorgensen Does your regex include capture groups like in the given example?

Answer (score 7):

As a one liner, try:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1 $2\n" if /^--ERROR/ && /Name="(.*?)"\s+Age="(.*?)"/;'
```

This is a lot like using sed, but with Perl syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate question of "how do I use perl like sed?" is best answered with s2p, the sed to perl converter.   Given the command line, "sed $script", simply invoke "s2p $script" to generate a (typically unreadable) perl script that emulates sed for the given set of commands.

Comment: s2p no longer comes with perl but you can get it in the module [App::s2p](https://www.metacpan.org/module/App::s2p)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to comments :

```
my @a = <>; # Reading entire file into an array
chomp @a;   # Removing extra spaces
@a = grep {/ERROR/} @a; # Removing lines that do not contain ERROR
# mapping with sed-like regexp to keep only names and ages :
@a = map {s/^.*Name=\"([a-z]+)\" Age=\"([0-9]+)\".*$/$1 $2/; $_} @a; 
print join " ",@a; # print of array content
```

Comment: I would recommend against reading everything into one array and then processing it. Just read it line-by-line.

Comment: Don't take it for you, Matthew, but may I ask why ?

Comment: If you have a file larger than your RAM, your system would hang.  That's why.  But more importantly you just don't need to store the entire file in an array - storing the current line in a *single* variable would suffice.  Wouldn't it ? :)  Or best, just use $_ .

Comment: Well, may be i'm wrong, but in case of large file, I use Tie::File.

I was confronted to a not so large (~30mo) file parsing that took ~180 seconds to perform with a while(<>) loop, against ~4 seconds in slurp mode.

As the OP doesn't defined memory usage over execution time as a criteria, i don't think my answer deserve a '-' :(